# Pass info back to parent into its WebBrowser Control

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

Visual Studio 2010, Visual Basic .NET

---

***EDIT AGAIN***
I have determined that what I am trying to do, cannot be done.

---

I have a form `frmContent` with a WebBrowser Control `wbContent`. 
If you click on an image link in wbContent, it opens a new form(frmImages) and loads the image into a WebBrowser `wbImages`.  I use a WebBrowser control for this because I use the same window to open tables written in html.

Anyway, when the user clicks a table link in `wbContent`, it opens `frmImages` and loads the html page for the table into `wbImages`.

I added a mouse down event listener in `wbImages` just like I have in `wbContent`.  When the user clicks a link in a table inside wbImages, it is suppose to open the link in its parent form, `frmContent`.

I have tried `wbImages.Stop()` to prevent `wbImages` from navigating, but that doesn't work.

I try setting focus to frmContent, and then loading the URL into the parent WebBrowser, wbContent, and that doesn't work.  Then only thing I can do to get it to work is to add a MessageBox before I send the URL to the parent window.

This code below works, but if I remove the MessageBox, it loads the URL in the wbImages.

```
Public Sub wpMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
    If e.MouseButtonsPressed = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim bookmarkElement = wbImages.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition)
        If bookmarkElement.GetAttribute("href").ToString() <> "" Then
            testUrl = bookmarkElement.GetAttribute("href").ToString()
            MessageBox.Show(testUrl)
            frmContent.Focus()
            frmContent.wbContent.Navigate(New Uri(testUrl))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

***EDIT***

If I remove the frmContent.wbContent.Navigate(New Uri(testUrl)), wbImages still navigates. I must have implemented a ReturnValue incorrectly, or my event handler is wrong and the .Stop() does not work either. Here is the whole event handler code before I made any changes from suggestions here.

```
Private Sub frmImages_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler wbImages.Document.MouseDown, AddressOf wpMouseDownEvent
End Sub

Private Sub wpMouseDownEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs)
    Dim event_html As New HtmlElementEventHandler(AddressOf wpMouseDown)
    event_html.Invoke(sender, e)
End Sub

Public Sub wpMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
  If e.MouseButtonsPressed = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
     Dim bookmarkElement = wbImages.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition)
     If bookmarkElement.GetAttribute("href").ToString() <> "" Then
        testUrl = bookmarkElement.GetAttribute("href").ToString()
        'Need testUrl to be passed to the Navigation for wbContent
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [`ReturnValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementeventargs.returnvalue.aspx) of the event to `False` to prevent the default action, just like you would return `false` from an `onclick` handler in Javascript to prevent the default action.

---

It may be that the event handler runs on a different thread, or that the sequence of events simply doesn't work when used in this fashion. I suspect the MessageBox makes it work because it runs an event loop which processes some message that needs to be processed before another navigaiton can occur. Either of these situations could potentially be resolved by deferring the navigation with `BeginInvoke`. I'm not a VB.NET programmer, but something like this, I think:

```
frmContent.BeginInvoke(Function ()
                           frmContent.Activate()
                           frmContent.wbContent.Navigate(New Uri(testUrl))
                       End Function)
```

Comment: Ok I was successfully able to prevent wbImages from navigating but I cannot get it to focus on frmContent to load the link into wbContent.

Comment: Have you tried `Activate`? From MSDN: "Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate method for forms."

Comment: Just tried frmContent.Activate() and frmContent.Select().  Neither change focus to frmConent and wbContent does not navigate to the url.  How would a messageBox make this work?  If We know why the MessageBox makes this work, maybe we can mimic it without an actual messageBox.

Comment: I expect the MessageBox makes it work because it has a message pump. See the updated answer.